How to write integration tests for Hangfire jobs?
I want to test my background job, that has been written for Hangfire. Basically job downloads a couple of files to the local file system, sends them to the custom dll and saves the output to Azure Blob Storage.
By testing I want to achieve next goals:

Verify that job works as expected: creates necessary folders, calls the dll, sends files to the Blob Storage (Azurite), logs curtain outcomes.
Verify, that implemented job can be properly activated in Hangfire for processing: job arguments are properly processed, job is properly executed by Hangfire with all dependencies, used storage properly serialized implemented types.

At first I tried to focus on the first goal by testing job implementation in isolation, mocking and doubling all dependencies, but it appeared to be dull and too bulky. Many custom doubles and mocks made these tests to hard to maintain, plus their value became questionable.
On the next try, to achieve both goals, I tried to implement integration tests using BackgroundJobServer, which will be shared across tests (for optimization) to run implemented job under different setups and assert the result. It also might require bulky set ups, but usage of the real Hangfire package increases the value of these tests.
This is the setup of the testable BackgroundJobServer, which should process jobs, that will be scheduled by tests.
public sealed class JobServerFixture : IDisposable
{
    internal BackgroundJobServer JobServer { get; set; }
    // custom activator, returns job instances with mocked dependencies
    internal TestJobActivator JobActivator { get; private set; }
    public Guid Id { get; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    public JobServerFixture()
    {
        this.JobActivator = new TestJobActivator();

        // can be replaced with in-memory storage
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseRedisStorage(
            "connectionString",
            new RedisStorageOptions
            {
                Prefix = "test:",
            });

        this.JobServer = new BackgroundJobServer(
            new BackgroundJobServerOptions
            {
                Activator = this.JobActivator,
                WorkerCount = 1,
                ServerName = this.Id.ToString()
            });
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.JobServer.Dispose();
    }
}

Now integration test can look like on the snippet below. I'm using xUnit and its IClassFixture to share context between tests:
public sealed class JobTests : IClassFixture<JobServerFixture>
{
    private readonly JobServerFixture fixture;

    public JobTests(JobServerFixture fixture)
    {
        this.fixture = fixture;
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Test()
    {
        // ARRANGE.
        var jobClient = new BackgroundJobClient();

        // ACT.
        string? jobId = jobClient.Enqueue<Job>(
            x => x.ExecuteAsync(
                new JobArguments(1, 2, 3), null,
                default(CancellationToken)));

        
        // ASSERT. 
        this.fixture.JobActivator.IsLastMessageEquals(
                 LogLevel.Information,
                 "Expected message")
             .Should()
             .BeTrue();
        // other assertions...
    }
}

The main issue is that the test doesn't wait for job completion, performs all assertions (which are failed of course) and disposes launched BackgroundJobServer clearing out everything.
How to make tests wait for job completion? I want to wait for a moment when it's fully done by the launched BackgroundJobSerber instanse and do assertions of used dependencies.
Or maybe there are other, easier approaches to cover mentioned goals?
EDIT: I could accomplish await of enqueued tasks by using JobStorage object. After that I can do any assertions to validate the results of the completed job:
    public async Task WaitForJobCompletionAsync(string jobId)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            StateData? stateName = this.JobStorage.GetConnection()
                                       .GetStateData(jobId);

            if (stateName.Name is "Succeeded" or "Failed")
            {
                break;
            }

            await Task.Delay(50)
                      .ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }

